# How to insert tags in static html in play framework

Tags: static, tags, playframework

I create a tag whose content is static,

for example: header.html

then I insert to a static html eg: about.htm,

when open:

http://localhost:9000/about.htm

still get #{header /} in the browser.

how to solve it?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we can't see any code?

Comment: In fact, I don't want to render the html via a controller, since all of the page is static, I just want add a tag to make the page simple.  is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put your `header.html` file in the `app/views/tags` directory?

**update:** Since you said you did, it's probably because you need to render the html server side via a controller.

So try creating a controller and putting it in the controllers package.  Something like this:

```
package controllers;

public final class About extends Controller {

    public static void about() {
        render();
    }
}
```

And then make sure that `about.htm` lives in the folder `app/views/About`. *Note: I'm not entirely sure, but you might need to rename `about.htm` to be `about.html` (but probably not, but just keep it in mind if it doesn't work for you)*.

So to get the controller to render the about.htm with the resolved header.html, you will need to hit the url `http://localhost:9000/About/about`

of course, you can clean that url up by adding this to the `routes` file:

```
GET /about    About.about
```

Using the above, you can simply hit this url `http://localhost:9000/about`.

Comment: YES, it need to render the html in server side via a controller.

Comment: In fact, I don't want to render the html via a controller, since all of the page is static, I just want add a tag to make the page simple. is there a solution?

Comment: maybe do some searching on solutions for client side includes in html in google or stackoverflow